# Network does not work in Ubuntu or Linux Mint, works in Windows 7

Tags: wireless, networking, connection, wired

I have no wired or wireless connectivity in Ubuntu or Linux mint. I have tried Gnome and KDE versions of both. Networking works in Windows 7 on the same machine. 
In the Ubuntu 12.10 Network manager (in the control panel), I only have two items listed on the left: "Wired" and "Network Proxy".

"Wired" only says "Cable Unplugged" and my MAC address. The options button is not clickable.

The only interface I could add in this menu is VPN.

This is my output of ifconfig -a

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:c9:xx:xx:xx  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:432 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35296 (35.2 KB)  TX bytes:35296 (35.2 KB)
```

Comment: What exact model of wired and wireless adapters do you have? If you don't know, what model of computer? Are you trying to connect to wired or wireless?

Comment: neither wired nor wireless is working. I have a Dell Vostro 1400.
Dell Wireless 1390 802.11g Wi-Fi Mini Card
Integrated 10/100 Network Card and Modem